# Does requiring an Play Services module in manifest.xml install for all apps or just the requestor

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-result-api

I'm implementing the `PickVisualMediaRequest` photo picker and have added the service to my manifest.xml telling Play Services to install its module for API levels under 30, as shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#device-availability

Does doing this mean that

1. other apps that don't include the service but use the same `PickVisualMediaRequest` flow will also utilize the module, or
2. this only impacts the app that includes the service in its mainfest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Including the service as required in the manifest does seem to impact other apps. I was able to test this.

1. Install two apps on a device from Android 4.4 (API level 19) through Android 10 (API level 29). Neither includes the service declared as required in the app manifest.

   - Pulling up the picker in either app shows the old UI.
2. Update one of the apps to include the required service in the manifest, but leave the other app alone.

   - Pulling up the picker on the updated app shows the new UI.
   - Pulling up the picker on the app that was *not* updated *also* shows the new UI.